# How to track a folder again when used "git rm -rf --cached folder_name" : Error: The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files

Tags: git, gitignore, dvc

I wanted to un-track my git files so I put `.dvc` inside my `.gitignore` file, and run

```
git rm -rf --cached .dvc
```

and then committed.

I realised my mistake soon and then wanted to add the files again . I tried deleting the `gitignore` file, commit, make a new `.gitignore` and then try adding but all is futile. `git add .dvc` does not track my files and using `git add .dvc/*` gives me error:

```
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
.dvc/cache
.dvc/tmp
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```

Running the command `git check-ignore -v .dvc/*` gives me:

```
.dvc/.gitignore:3:/cache    .dvc/cache
.dvc/.gitignore:2:/tmp  .dvc/tmp
```

What can be done now?

Comment: Git *never* tracks a folder. Git *only* tracks *files*. To track a file that would otherwise be ignored, well, read the message Git printed (`Use -f if...`).

Comment: I'm still confused about the motivation here, "wanted to un-track my git files". It seems like you wanted to remove DVC config files from the Git index, rather. May I ask why? What about other DVC metafiles like `dvc.yaml` or `.dvc` files?

Comment: @JorgeOrpinelPérez I actually didn't look inside and thought my `key` for remote storage would be exposed. Then I checked again in `.dvc` that it was in `.gitignore`. That's why I say that was a mistake but that doesn't matter because this one's a unique problem to me for `git`

Comment: @torek When I use `-f` my terminal just freezes. Nothing comes up. I tried tracking individual files inside `.dvc` but everytime I do this, my terminal just freezes.

Comment: It's not frozen, it's just taking a *very long time* to read through, compress, and check for duplicates for *every file* in those folders. Remember that `git add` of a folder path means "add every file you can find underneath here, except for ignored ones that aren't already tracked" and `-f` disables the "except for" part. You could be adding many gigabytes to your repository.

Comment: @torek ohhhhh!!! Now I got it. Makes sense as my `.dev/cache` has many files. Thank you.

Comment: If your secrets ever get to Git you need to rewrite the whole history of the repo for it to be safe. See https://secretaudit.com/docs/how-to-remove-secrets-from-git-history

Answer (score 1):

```
rm .gitignore  # or edit it to remove the .dvc entry
dvc add .dvc
```

> Using `.dvc/*` doesn't work because there's a .gitignore file inside that folder which prevents you from staging the `cache` and `tmp` sub-dirs -- which should definitely not be in Git.

Or just `git reset --hard abc1234` where `abc1234` is the commit before you un-tracked `.dvc/` (which you can find with `git log`).

p.s. why would you un-track DVC config files form Git though? Maybe you were looking for https://dvc.org/doc/command-reference/destroy or https://dvc.org/doc/user-guide/how-to/stop-tracking-data.